# How to show a boot animation preview?

Tags: java, android, preview, boot-animation

Hi i'm working on a simple boot animation app for my first app just to learn the basics and all. I'm now done with the app and have everything i wanted basically, except previews of the boot animations. I tried creating a gallery and showing an animated gif however as you probably know android doesn't support animated gifs natively.

So my question is this what is the best way to show previews of my boot animations. I've searched but found nothing that seemed like a good way of previewing them. So how should i approach this problem? Any sample code and or links to tutorials, even just ideas or suggestions on what i should do to approach this would be a significant help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `AnimationDrawable` can help you. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame).

Comment: Alright well i got that set up and working fine however i need the images to be read from the sdcard not the drawable folder of my application as i need to display a lot of animations so any solutions on how i can do that?

Comment: 1. Load images using `BitmapFactory` class. 2. Create an `AnimationDrawable` object in your code. 3. Add loaded bitmaps as frames using `AnimationDrawable.addFrame()` method. Bitmaps can be converted to drawables by calling `new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)`. 4. Set created `AnimationDrawable` as a background of some `View` and call drawables's `start()` method.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help will look into all of that stuff and will post my final solution when written

Comment: @Michael This can take a lot of memory, no?

Comment: @GFlam Have you done it? Only library I've found is very old: https://github.com/bq/android-bootanimation-checker , and I'm not sure about the license either...